# Converting Arduino UNO's analog pins to digital I/O

Tags: pins, servo

I am working on an Arduino UNO Project and running out of digital pins.

Can I convert the six analog pins to digital I/O and use them to drive servos?

Please suggest me a method

Comment: Just putting it out there that it is a [Uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno), not a UNO. It is not an acronym.

Answer (score 4):

A0 through A5 already have GPIO capability; treat them as you would [any other non-PWM pin](http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Servo).

A6 and A7, found in similar boards that use a SMD package, do not have any GPIO capability whatsoever and can only be used for analog input.

Comment: Please explain.  Can I use A1 To A6 to drive my servos Normally ??

Comment: Only PWM-capable pins can drive servos normally.

Comment: The servo library uses software pwm if I'm not mistaken. So you should be able to use any pin.

Comment: @RanjanJha: A0 to A5 can be referred to as  D14 to D20. You could use `digitalWrite(A0)`  or `digitalWrite(14)` and the effect would be the same.